# c++ reading txt file and store it in a matrix char by char

Tags: c++

I need to read a txt file and store it into a matrix (we suppose that it'a a 2x2 matrix). I have a problem with the code below (I semplified it to be more cleat):

```
#include<stdexcept>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class A{

private:

int **m;

void allocate_mem(int ***ptr){
    *ptr = new int *[2];
    (*ptr)[0] = new int[2*2];
    for(unsigned i = 1; i < 2; i++)
        (*ptr)[i] = (*ptr)[0] + i*2;
}

void read_file(string file_input){
    ifstream fin(file_input.c_str());
    allocate_mem(&m);
    char a;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            a = fin.get();
            if(a=="X"){     
 //ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
                m[i][j] = 1;
            }else{
                m[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }       
    }
    fin.close();        
}

public:

A(){
    throw logic_error("Error!");
}

A(string file_name){
    read_file(file_name);
}

~A(){
    delete[] m[0];
    delete[] m;
}

};
```

input.txt

```
XX
 X
```

I want to store a 2x2 matrix whose elemets are:

```
11
01
```

Comment: What is happening? Does it compile? If so, what output are you getting instead of what you expect?

Comment: `if(a=="X")` should be `if(a=='X')` with single quotes

Comment: It doesn't compile. The error is indicated after // in the code.

Comment: `int ***ptr` Three stars... The cuality of C++ code could be measured by the inverse of the number of pointers which you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple: **Write C++ instead of C**

Use standard containers instead of manual memory management.
Also, if you know the size of the data at compile-time, why do you use dynamic memory?

```
int m[2][2];

void read_file(const std::string& file_input) {
    ifstream fin(file_input.c_str());
    char a;

    if( !fin ) throw;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            a = fin.get();
            if (a == 'X') { // '' is for characters, "" for strings. Thats why the compiler
                m[i][j] = 1;// warns you (You are comparing the char[], which is decayed to
            } else {        // char*, with the integer value of the char variable)
                m[i][j] = 0;
            }
         }
     }
//Close not needed (RAII)
}
```